# python speech to text and voice level differences visualisation

Tags: python, text-to-speech

Hi am using pyttsx for converting text to speech and then vise versa making a sort of automatic call replying system.
Where one will ask questions and then python will convert it into text and reply with voice(Like SIRI in apple)
Now what i want is to have a tool which will show different values of bar when the system is replying.
Just like we are having in Microphone. Everytime it receives a voice the sound bar goes up..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLOC0.png)

Comment: check out this gist : https://gist.github.com/livibetter/4118062

Answer (score 0):

A tool to make that is the standard [`turtle` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) for output, the necessary calculations (how much the bar must go up) can be done without any library.